# VBScript Error "Invalid or Unqualified Reference" with SendKeys Method

Tags: vbscript, compiler-errors, runtime-error, sendkeys, wsh

I am getting the following error with my code in a .vbs file:

```
C:\...\Root_VBS_Script_1.vbs(19, 1) Microsoft
VBScript runtime error: Invalid or unqualified reference

1 was unexpected at this time.
```

The .vbs file is as follows:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set args = WScript.Arguments
arg1 = args.Item(0)

Dim filename

filename = ""&arg1&""


WshShell.SendKeys "root -b" //opens root in batch mode
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.AppActivate ROOT_session
WshShell.SendKeys ".x analysis.C"
wshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.SendKeys ".x double_gaus.C"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.AppActivate ROOT_session
WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs("&filename&.pdf&")"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
WshShell.SendKeys ".q"
WshShell.SendKeys "~"

WScript.Quit 1
```

I am using the send keys method to run a program called root (developed by CERN) out of a .vbs file called from a batch file. I am attaching the filename as a parameter when calling the .vbs file. I am uncertain as to why I am getting this error, but I do know that the send keys method opens root and works up until it is supposed to save c1 as the given filename and type.

Can anyone help me resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is your culprit:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs("&filename&.pdf&")"
```

There is no variable `.pdf` that could be concatenated. It's not even a valid variable name because of the leading dot. You probably meant to concatenate the variable `filename` with the string `.pdf` here. Change the above line to this:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs(" & filename & ".pdf)"
```

On a more general note: why are you using VBScript (and particularly `SendKeys`) in the first place? If I understand the [documentation](ftp://root.cern.ch/root/doc/ROOTUsersGuideHTML/ch07s03.html#d5e6570) correctly you can run `root` scripts from within other `root` scripts, so there's no need for another scripting language or unreliable methods like `SendKeys`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try it in a second. For your question, I do understand the unreliability of SendKeys and I do know you can have scripts within scripts in root, but currently I am not experienced enough yet using root to undertake that, and I needed a quick way to analyze my current data set for a deadline coming up. Ideally, yes I would do it within root, and soon I will.

Comment: On a more general manner, this error is triggerred when using a method on a line starting with a dot, without including it in a **With** and **End With** block : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-or-unqualified-reference